# problem when changing the keyboard layout in tiny core linux

Tags: keyboard-layout, tinycore

I have installed tiny core linux, and I need a different keyboard layout; I searched on the internet, and I've read this line,

```
sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/qwerty/fi-latin9.kmap
```

but it doesn't work, the shell says: "-sh: can't open [...]: no such file"
http://tinycorelinux.net/faq.html#keyboard

EDIT: maybe I've found a possible solution, I need to connect tiny core linux to the internet, and after that type,

```
tce-load -wi Xorg-7.7-lang-it
```

but it gives me a server error: http not found, 404 error.

I use a virtual machine (virtual box), do you think it's a problem of the virtual machine?

Comment: So what files do you have in `/usr/share/kmap/qwerty`? Does any of those work?

Comment: @Peregrino69 how to list them?

Comment: Doesn't `ls /usr/share/kmap/qwerty` work???

Comment: it says: "ls: [path]: no such file or directory"

Comment: is it possible that the problem is the virtual machine?

Comment: hey, Gabriel, not to be gatekeeping anything, but I think if knowing how to list directories might make tinycorelinux a bit of a suboptimal Linux distribution for you. But if you like the challenge more than that you need a system that you can actually work with – don't let anything stop you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller i need to use that for a college course, I don't want to use it but I have to

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini :) That's a valid reason. Cool course, really taking you for a ride on a truly minimal system; can imagine it's a bit exhausting at times.

Comment: Ah. I think I see your problem. I installed TinyCore on a VM, and the path is indeed invalid. On a vanilla installation I only have `/usr/share/kmap` which contains one file, `us.kmap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Exit to Prompt
- Install extension `kmap.tcz`:

```
tce-load -wi kmaps.tcz
```

- This will populate `/usr/share/kmap`-directory. Options for Italian:

  - it-ibm.kmap
  - it.kmap
  - it2.kmap
- Load the desired keymap with

```
sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/qwerty/it.kmap
```

- `startx` to get back to GUI

Tested on freshly installed [TinyCore](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/downloads.html) on VirtualBox (boots to GUI by default).